# Python - repetitive blocks of text

Tags: python, perl

I am new to Python but I have been using Perl for some time. In Perl, in order to limit search of an file to specific block of text, I would write something like below:

```
if (/start_line/ ... /end_line/) {
   do something here
}
```

The condition `/start_line/ ... /end_line/` starts being true once the `/start_line/` regex matches and then continues being true until after the `/end_line/` regex matches. In a loop that reads input line by line, this would execute the if-block for all lines between the start line and the end line, inclusive.

How can I express the same condition in Python?

Comment: "limit search of an file to specific block of text" is quite vague, and we don't necessarily know enough perl to know what this "if (/start_line/ ... /end_line/")" stuff __really__ does.  Also the best answer might depends on the context (what's in the file, how you want to use it etc).

Comment: this is known as the "flip-flop operator" in Perl (and it's two dots `..`, not three). google "flip-flop operator in Python" for more info

Comment: @beasy: It is *either* two dots *or* three, depending on how you want it to behave at the end of the range.

Comment: @bruno: *"we don't necessarily know enough perl to know what this ... stuff really does"* That's fine, but it's not a reason to avoid asking the question just because some people (like you, presumably) don't know the answer.

Comment: @Borodin did I mean the OP shouldn't have asked this ??? Please re-read, I just ask for clarifications about what he's trying to do so he has _more_ chances to get a good answer.

Comment: @bruno: Then it seems odd to attack the contents of the OP, instead of simply asking questions to clarify your doubts as usual.

Comment: @Borodin I didn't "attack" anything nor anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're referring to the Perl's flip-flop operator (`..`). Basically, it sets a boolean flag to true when it encounters the first condition, and back to false after it encounters the second (start and end lines inclusive). Looking at it that way, it's fairly simple to implement.

```
import re

flip = False;
for line in open(filename):
    if not flip and re.match('start-text',line): flip = True
    if flip:
        print(line)
        if re.match('end-text',line): flip = False
```

Comment: for some reason I cant make it work this way but seems simplier !

Comment: @melpomene, Fixed.

Comment: I had also accidentally flipped the args to the regex match. that's why it didn't work for OP. fixed now

Answer (score 3):

What if you try something like that?

```
start_line = "line 1"
end_line = "line 2"
in_block = False
line_block = []

with open("file.txt") as search:
    for line in search:
        line = line.rstrip()  # remove '\n' at end of line
        if line == start_line:
            in_block = True
        elif line == end_line:
            line_block.append(line)
            in_block = False

       if in_block:
           line_block.append(line)
```

Comment: You shouldn't post answers based on wild guesses.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Just because you don't know Perl doesn't mean that others don't. This answer is a fairly accurate translation of Perl's flip-flop operator `...` into Python. It is not a wild guess.

Comment: The second one is wrong. If a sought block doesn't exist, then you crash, and if there are several, you only report the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I initially wrote a generator that yielded lines from the ﬁrst
matching block *only* (see edit history) but an edit made me
reconsider my first proposal, because the expected behaviour is to
execute the `if` body on every matching block of text.

My new proposal is again a generator that, of course, by default
yields the lines from the matching text blocks "forever" but, using an
optional keyword argument, can also process the matching blocks a
maximum number (`count`) of times.

A proof of concept follows

````
def from_beg_to_end(filename, beg, end, count=0):

    '''Yields the lines from `filename` like in `sed -n /beg/,/end/p`

    By default (for `count=0`) if the file contains multiple blocks
    all the blocks are output, for `count` greater than zero the number
    of blocks whose lines are returned is _at most_ `count.

    Example of use:

    for line in from_beg_to_end(filename, 'a', b'):
        ...```

    inside = False
    for line in open(filename):
        if not inside:
            if beg in line: inside = True
        if inside:
            yield line
            if end in line:
                count = count-1
                if count==0: return
                inside = False
````

that uses a simple string match.  It should be easy to adapt the code
above to support regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

The Perl solution implements flip flop operator which retains the state between successive loops. The other solutions have already implemented this by updating a flag variable. One can also write a class so that the status of previous matches are retained in the instance variable. An example is given below. This is the closest I could get to the elegant Perl syntax

```
#Fileblock.py
import re

class Block_Extract:
    def __init__(self):
        self.state = False
    def test(self, lines, start, end):
        if not self.state:
            self.m1 = re.search(start, lines)
        self.m2 = re.search(end, lines)
        if self.m1 and not self.m2:
            self.state = True
            return self.state
        if self.m2:
            self.state = False
            return True


start = "line3"
end = "line7"
fileblock = Block_Extract()
with open("Block_Test") as fp:
    for lines in fp:
        lines = lines.rstrip()
        if fileblock.test(lines, start, end):
            print lines

$ cat Block_Test 
This is line1
This is line2
This is line3
This is line4
This is line5
This is line6
This is line7
This is line8
This is line9
This is line10
$ python Fileblock.py 
This is line3
This is line4
This is line5
This is line6
This is line7
```

Comment: somehow I have issue to understand classes but this solution also works ! Cheers